# How to update only one sub row inside main row in sail.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I am developing sails.js application

application model

```
name: String,
address:String,
appSettings: {
    header: String,
    color : String,
    font: String,
}
```

I use independent update query **update color** and **update font** in appSetting

I have added both update query Here

for **color** row inside appSettings

```
var data = {
        appSettings:{
            color : 'red'
        }
    };

 var query = {_id:'xxxxxxxxxx'};

 Application.update(query,data).exec(function(err,application) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.send({message:'Success'});
});
```

for **font** row inside appSettings

```
var data = {
        appSettings:{
            font : 'Times-New-Roman'
        }
    };

 var query = {_id:'xxxxxxxxxx'};

 Application.update(query,data).exec(function(err,application) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.send({message:'Success'});
});
```

Result **JSON** file is,

```
{
 "name" : "Water Colors",
 "address" : "No 25, Kandy Road, Colombo",
 "appSettings": {
    "font" : "Times-New-Roman"
 }
}
```

Problem is, When run one update query appSettings are overwrite

How can I update only font row inside appSettings row with out overwrite color row in appSettings?

Hope answer, If not clear comment pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var data =  {        
     "appSettings.color" : 'red'
 };

 var query = {_id:'xxxxxxxxxx'};

 Application.update(query,data).exec(function(err,application) {
   if (err) res.send(err);
   res.send({message:'Success'});
 });
```

Comment: But if you  use **db.application.update(query,data)** then you have use $set

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **[`native()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native)** method of the model to retrieve the underlying instance of the native Mongo driver's collection, with that you can then perform raw Mongo queries/operations. The native **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** operator will update the fields as follows:

```
var data = {
    appSettings:{
        color : 'red'
    }
};

var query = {_id:'xxxxxxxxxx'};

Application.native(function(err, collection) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);    
    collection.update(
        query,
        { "$set": data },
        function (err, results) {
            if (err) return res.serverError(err);
            res.send({message: 'Success'});
        }
    );
});
```